# Reaction Roles Discord JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, chatbot

I'm trying to code reaction roles into my bot but I am having trouble with the message ids and reaction ids. The problem I'm encountering is that the message.id when I first post this message is somehow different to the reaction.message.id of when someone is reacting to the message, even though it is the exact same message. Is there any reason why the id of the message somehow changes from the posting of the message to the reactions of users? Here is my code.

```
async function ReactionRoles(client){

    client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => { 

        acceptablerankemojis = ["Radiant_Valorant", "Immortal_Valorant", "Diamond_Valorant", "Platinium_Valorant", "Gold_Valorant", "Silver_Valorant", "Bronze_Valorant", "Iron_Valorant"]

        if (reaction.message.partial){await reaction.message.fetch()};
        if (reaction.partial){await reaction.fetch()};
        if (user.bot == true) {return};
        if (!reaction.message.guild) {return};
        if (acceptablerankemojis.includes(reaction.emoji.name) == false){
                
            user.send(`**That is not a valid reaction, please only use the reactions listed.**`)
            reaction.remove().catch(error => {

                console.log("There was an error removing the reactions.")
            })
        }

        const getMessage = await reactionScheme.find({

        }, {
    
            name: 1,
            guildId: 1,
            channelId: 1,
            messageId: 1
        })

        getMessage.forEach(async element => {

            console.log("Arrived between")
            console.log(element.messageId)
            console.log(reaction.message.id)
            
            if (element.messageId == reaction.message.id){

                console.log("Arrived2")
                var name = element.name
                var guildId = element.guildId
                switch (name){

                    case "ValorantRanks":
                        switch(guildId){

                            case "814021508052942870":

                                console.log("Arrived 3")
                                const radiantrole = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Radiant");
                                const immortalrole = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Immortal");
                                const diamondrole = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Diamond");
                                const platinumrole = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Platinum");
                                const goldrole = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Gold");
                                const silverrole = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Silver");
                                const bronzerole = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Bronze");
                                const ironrole = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Iron");
    
                                switch(reaction.emoji.name){

                                    case "Radiant_Valorant":
                                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(radiantrole)
                                    break
                                    case "Immortal_Valorant":
                                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(immortalrole)
                                    break
                                    case "Diamond_Valorant":
                                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(diamondrole)
                                    break
                                    case "Platinium_Valorant":
                                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(platinumrole)
                                    break
                                    case "Gold_Valorant":
                                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(goldrole)
                                    break
                                    case "Silver_Valorant":
                                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(silverrole)
                                    break
                                    case "Bronze_Valorant":
                                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(bronzerole)
                                    break
                                    case "Iron_Valorant":
                                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(ironrole)
                                    break
                                }
                            break
                        }
                    break
                }
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `reactionScheme`?

Comment: reactionScheme is a schema from mongoDB which i use to store the guildid, channelid, and messageid